# Highcharts view Fullscreen not resizing after print

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If i choose to view fullscreen before trying to print it works fine.

However, if, after printing, i try and view full screen the chart doesn't update to fill the screen and only displays at the same size as normal.

what am i doing wrong here?

```
events: {
    beforePrint() {
        this.exportSVGElements[0].box.hide();
        this.exportSVGElements[1].hide();
        bottomMargin = this.marginBottom;
        this.resetParams = [this.chartWidth, this.chartHeight, false];
        this.setSize(1000, 700, false);
        this.update({
            chart: { marginBottom: 350 },
        }, false);
    },
    afterPrint() {
        this.exportSVGElements[0].box.show();
        this.exportSVGElements[1].show();
        this.setSize.apply(this, this.resetParams); // eslint-disable-line prefer-spread
        this.update({
            chart: { marginBottom: bottomMargin },
        }, true);
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Edited how you were resetting setSize after printing
2. Changed this to chart, as the update method want the name of the option, not to object itself.

```js
let options= {

    chart: {
  events: {
    beforePrint() {
        this.exportSVGElements[0].box.hide();
        this.exportSVGElements[1].hide();
        console.log(this.marginBottom)
        bottomMargin = this.marginBottom;
        this.resetParams = [this.chartWidth, this.chartHeight, false];
        this.setSize(1000, 700, false);
        this.update({
            chart: { marginBottom: 350 },
        }, false);
    },
    afterPrint() {
        this.exportSVGElements[0].box.show();
        this.exportSVGElements[1].show();
        this.setSize(...this.resetParams);
        this.update({chart: {marginBottom: bottomMargin }}, true);
    },
},
  },

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2017'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

}

let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Basic line chart showing trends in a dataset. This chart includes the
        <code>series-label</code> module, which adds a label to each line for
        enhanced readability.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. i can confirm it was correct in my codebase, the 'this' in the update instead of chart was just an error in me converting it from my project to here. thanks for the setSize though. my linting was screaming at me about that and i couldnt work it out. Though this doesnt solve the initial issue my end though

Comment: Hi, see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marensiusb/4co0asxp/
Fullscreen did work after printing.

Could you give me a jsfiddle, if you continue to encounter the issue

Comment: its strange. im trying to reproduce this in a jsfiddle but struggling. however in my app, after print and the setSize is applied with the resetParams, when i try and view fullscreen the chart remains at the dimensions defined in the reset params. i can get the width to update by setting the resetParams chartWidth to be null, and the same with the height, but the problem with that, is because i shift the legend under the pie chart on small screens, having the chartHeight set to null means that the piechart then overlaps the legend because there is no longer a fixed height.